# Apache2 redirect subdirectory to port

Tags: linux, apache, http, ubuntu, redirect

If I redirect from the root directory to a different port everything works fine with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost> 

http://www.example.com/ -> http://www.example.com:8080/
```

But if i try the followig configuration to redirect from a subdirectory to a different port it redirects to port 80.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass /example http://localhost:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverse /example http://localhost:8080/example/
</VirtualHost> 

http://www.example.com/example -> http://www.example.com:80/example/
```

What's wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Where did you specify the DocumentRoot?

Comment: You need to be consistent with trailing slashes in ProxyPass rule.